# show asp.net progress bar for multiple operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, progress-bar

I need to show asp.net progress bar for three operations on webpage. First,when file upload the progress bar should show 33 % and message 'file upload started'. Once uploaded it should show message 'validating file data' and progress 66%. At third round, it should show 'automatching data' with 99%.

I have three methods that will be called one by one. I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution for this type of problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to attempt a solution yourself, and if you experience issues with your code, post back here.

Comment: There are some solution that you must find and fix by yourself - not everything is for free on google search results.

Comment: Sir,i tried the code.I am calling three method inside button click event.In each method,I am using loop which changes the label text.When one method executes, label should show 'file uploading' and same for other two methods. But the text in label is not changing.Please help.

Comment: It's practically impossible to help without any code. Edit your question, add in the relevant code (emphasis on *relevant*), and perhaps someone can give you a hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show progress bar you need to introduce some java script or jquery code. I am sharing a sample code you can take idea from here

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: left">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="return ProgressBar()" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
        <br />
        <div id="divUpload" style="display: none">
            <div style="width: 300pt; text-align: center;">Uploading...</div>
            <div style="width: 300pt; height: 20px; border: solid 1pt gray">
                <div id="divProgress" runat="server" style="width: 1pt; height: 20px; background-color: Gray; display: none">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 300pt; text-align: center;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPercentage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text=""></asp:Label>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var size = 2;
    var id = 0;

    function ProgressBar() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value != "") {
            document.getElementById("divProgress").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("divUpload").style.display = "block";
            id = setInterval("progress()", 20);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Select a file to upload");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function progress() {
        size = size + 1;
        if (size > 299) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        }
        document.getElementById("divProgress").style.width = size + "pt";
        document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentage.ClientID %>").
            firstChild.data = parseInt(size / 3) + "%";
    }

</script>

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do code here to saving a file from fileupload control
    //FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("path");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
    Label1.Text = "Upload successfull!";
}
```

Here is the source url - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26668/Showing-progress-bar-while-uploading-a-file-in-an